# what is the main function for the propertiesmethods in constructor

Tags: javascript

Below  are some code

```
var Foo=function(){
   this.doSomething1=function(){ 
      //do something

   }

};
Foo.prototype.doSomething2=function(){

     //do something
};
```

if I change it to

```
var Foo=function(){


};
Foo.prototype.doSomething1=function(){

  //do something
};
Foo.prototype.doSomething2=function(){

  //do something
};
```

the second block of code almost can do any thing same as the first one.
but it has very clear inherit relationship on prototype chain.

What is the advantage for the first code block?

Your comment welcome

Comment: In first approach, `doSomething1` is a part of every object and if you try `Object.hasOwnProperty` this will return true. Prototype are more for generic functions that are shared across objects

Comment: Disadvantage: doSomething1 will be stamped out for every instance and consuming memory. doSomething2 exists only once.